Mostrar gráfica con solo curvas en lugar de barras y curvas en R
Tengo una gráfica de actividad anual de especies durante meses y por horas, pero sale gráfica de barras y curvas. Quiero solo curvas, ¿cómo hago?

   # Cargar los datos
    x <- read.csv("C:/Users/maria/Desktop/WWF/actividad completo todo.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
        
   # Convertir hora a radianes ajustados a un día de 24 horas
    x$h <- (x$hora2) * (pi * 2) / 24
        
   # Comprobar los datos únicos de la columna "mes"
      print(unique(x$mes))
        
   # Verificar el tipo de datos de la columna "mes"
     print(class(x$mes))
        
   # Convertir la columna "mes" a factor y verificar los niveles
     x$mes <- as.factor(x$mes)
            print(levels(x$mes))
        
   # Obtener especies únicas
    unique_species <- unique(x$sonoespecie)
        
   # Recorrer cada especie única
     for (species in unique_species) {
          
   # Crear una lista vacía para almacenar los modelos ajustados para cada mes
    fitted_models <- list()
          
   # Filtrar los datos para la especie actual
    subset_data <- subset(x, sonoespecie == species)
          
   # Obtener los meses únicos para la especie actual
    unique_months <- sort(unique(subset_data$mes))

   # Crear un vector de nombres de meses en español basado en los meses únicos
    month_names <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", 
           "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")[unique_months]
          
   # Recorrer cada mes único y ajustar el modelo de actividad
     for (month in unique_months) {
            subset_data_month <- subset(subset_data, mes == month)
            mod <- fitact(subset_data_month$h, rep = 100, sample = "data")
            
   # Almacenar los modelos ajustados en la lista
    fitted_models[[length(fitted_models) + 1]] <- list(
              model = mod,
              month_name = month_names[month]
            )
          }
          
   # Inicializar el gráfico para la especie actual
    plot(fitted_models[[1]]$model, xlab = "Hora del dia", ylab = "Actividad", main = species, cex.lab = 1.3)
          
   # Recorrer cada modelo ajustado y trazar las curvas en el mismo gráfico
    for (i in 1:length(fitted_models)) {
            model <- fitted_models[[i]]$model
            scaled_pdf <- model@pdf * 3.8  # Suponiendo que quieres escalar la pdf por 3.8
            lines(scaled_pdf, col = rainbow(length(fitted_models))[i], lwd = 1.5)
           }
          
   # Agregar una leyenda para los meses
    legend("topright", legend = month_names, col = rainbow(length(fitted_models)), lwd = 1.5, cex = 0.8)
          
   # Guardar el gráfico
    filename <- paste("C:/Users/maria/Desktop/WWF/graficas actividad anual por meses/graficas 
            actividad anual por meses", species, ".png", sep="")
            png(filename, width = 623, height = 724)
            plot(fitted_models[[1]]$model, xlab = "Hora del dia", ylab = "Actividad", main = species, 
            cex.lab = 1.3)
            for (i in 1:length(fitted_models)) {
            model <- fitted_models[[i]]$model
            scaled_pdf <- model@pdf * 3.8
            lines(scaled_pdf, col = rainbow(length(fitted_models))[i], lwd = 1.5)
            }
            legend("topright", legend = month_names, col = rainbow(length(fitted_models)), lwd = 1.5, cex 
             = 0.8)
           dev.off()
           }


Agregale el siguiente parámetro a la función plot: plot(..., data = "none"), es decir, en:
plot(fitted_models[[1]]$model, 
     xlab = "Hora del dia", 
     ylab = "Actividad",
     main = species, 
     cex.lab = 1.3, 
     data = "none")

